# Full dictation mode using voice recognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am wondering if there is any way to record whatever I say in full dictation. What I mean by that is for example if I have a program, recording whatever is being picked up by the microphone and writing that information to a .txt file. How can I make so the program doesn't just "guess" the sentences? Because I find that using dictations like this.

```
DictationGrammar spellingDictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar("grammar:dictation#spelling");
spellingDictationGrammar.Name = "spelling dictation";
spellingDictationGrammar.Enabled = true;
recEngine.LoadGrammar(spellingDictationGrammar);

//question dictation grammar
DictationGrammar customDictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar("grammar:dictation");
customDictationGrammar.Name = "question dictation";
customDictationGrammar.Enabled = true;
recEngine.LoadGrammar(customDictationGrammar);
```

Just guesses whatever is being said. It is not even near accurate. Is there anyway to add a dictation or go around so it gets somewhat close to accurate?

Comment: A "guess" is the best you can get with voice recognition.

Comment: You need AI. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/speech/ . No doubt there are others. Almost certainly more accurate than the built-in speech recogniser in Windows. But as trailmax says, it's still only ever a best-guess. Computers cannot (yet) understand and transcribe speech with 100% accuracy (then again, neither can humans, generally)

Comment: thanks for the answers so far!, hmm okay , can i make it more accurate with the speech recognition inside c#? i rather not switch because i have came a long long way on my project now and this is suppose to be the last feature ^^

Comment: Not really I don't think, unless you can train it to your voice better. The software is what is it, you can't change it.